# Keeping wrapper remain centered when zooming out

Tags: html, css, browser, zooming

Currently when I zoom out, all the content goes to the left or right side. But I want to keep the content centered like [this page](http://www.vg.no) for example. [Here is the website](http://www.fantasylab.no/fantasy) which I want to keep the content centered when I zoom out.

Here is the body and wrapper CSS:

```
 body {
    background: #0a0a0a none repeat scroll 0 0;
    font: 14px/20px "Conv_Gotham-Medium",Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    min-width: 320px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
 }

#wrapper{
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to keep something centered is to set `margin: 0 auto` and a specific `width` (or a `max-width` to keep it more dynamic). `margin: 0 auto` causes the horizontal margin to equally fill the remaining space while the vertical margin stays 0.

*e.g. if your window width is 1280px and your #wrapper has a width of 1000px, both margin-left and margin-right will have 140px which leads to a centered wrapper*

Live Example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QydNYo?editors=110

Answer (score 0):

You seem to use the bootstrap framework.

Did you consider adding an additional class to your col-md-12, most conveniently trough `jQuery` with css-selectors or just plain CSS?

In your case like:

```
$(".webdesign-holder .col-md-12").css("max-width", value);
$(".webdesign-holder .col-md-12").css("margin", "0 auto");
```

OR

```
.webdesign-holder .col-md-12 {max-width:value;margin:0 auto}
```